# How can I emulsify Beeswax with Aloe Vera Gel?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment

I was looking thru ingredients for non-silicone based makeup primers and two ingredients always seem to be used: aloe vera gel and some type of wax, like jojoba wax, plus some type of oil to thin out the consistency like sweet almond oil or apricot kernel oil.

I thought it'd be interesting to see if it'd be possible to see if I could make my own, not least the companies that make them charge an arm and a leg for them.

My question is: what procedure and chemicals would you use to emulsify aloe gel with beeswax to make a cosmetic?

I vaguely remember that borax is used to make cold cream, maybe that'd come in useful?

Answer (score 3):

Aloe vera gel is water based, whereas beeswax is, well, wax-based. As they say, "oil and water don't mix" -- at least, not on their own.

So, the trick is to make them willing to mix. To do this, you need what's called an [emulsifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulsion#Emulsifiers). These are chemicals (natural or synthetic) that have both oily and watery parts to them, and thus are able to make oil and water play nice(r) with one another.  [Soap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soap) is one well-known, everyday example of an emulsifier; in particular, it's an example of a [surfactant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surfactant).

Anyways, you need an emulsifier. If you're looking to stick with natural products, probably the most readily available option is [lecithin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lecithin), commonly sourced from soy but also available derived from other plants such as sunflower.  While I don't have detailed recommendations, I would melt the beeswax together with lecithin and the aloe vera gel over very low heat, mixing thoroughly, then allowing the blend to cool.  You'll have to experiment until you find a ratio among these that gives the consistency you want in the final product.

Answer (score 2):

A great way to help is adding corn starch, which is an overall benefit. I blended various carrier oils, aloe vera, corn starch, cocoa butter (small percentage), and shea butter (small percentage). My product took a few times of trial and error! After 4 different times of adding ingredients, it finally blended well.